# What paints can I use on glass?

Tags: paint, medium-selection, glass

On [this website](http://bottlecrafters.com/collections/bottle-lamps), they propose some "bottle-lamps", e.g. this one:
[image]
I like the idea and would like to reproduce something similar.

I think the product can be improved by painting the bottle. So here's my question:

What are paints with following properties:

1. It *sticks on glass*.
2. It is *translucent*.

For what it's worth, note that the LEDs will produce a bit of heat inside the bottle, so this might be taken in consideration. But I guess this will not be an issue.

SIDE-NOTE: I think this can be done by [drilling a whole in the bottle](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-a-good-technique-for-drilling-holes-in-glass-bottles) and then simply fill the bottle with some LEDs guirlande. A workaround to avoid drilling, would be to turn the bottle upside down and make a kind of plinth to hold it. Then one can use the normal whole of the bottle to fill it with LEDs.

Comment: _It should resists the heat produced by the LEDs inside the bottle._ This shouldn't be an issue as the LEDs should not produce as much heat compared to incandescents.

Comment: Do the answers here help you? http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/545/what-paint-works-for-mock-stained-glass

Comment: @Matt Yes, I thought that the heat would not be a problem, but it's just in case this could hypothetically be an issue. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Matt Indeed, my question is a duplicate. So I simply marked it as such (I did not know that OP can close as duplicate themself)

Comment: Leave the dupe. Dupes are good! Just another sign post to the right content.

Comment: Indeed, this is a good dupe to have since it includes the heat component :)